# rowRange.setBackgroundColor is deprecated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

For a project, I use a function to set the color of background of the sheet.

This function works but Google inform "setBackgroundColor" is deprecated.

```
function bg() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  for (var i = range.getRow(); i < range.getLastRow(); i++) {
    rowRange = range.offset(i, 0, 1);
    status = rowRange.offset(0, 0).getValue();
    if (status !=0) {
      rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#000000");
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to use "setBackgrounds(colors)" but it doesn't work.

```
function new_bg() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var value = range.getValues();
  for(var i = 2; i <= value; i++){
    var colors = ["#000000"];
    range.setBackgrounds(colors);
  }
}
```

Comment: How is it that it "does not work"?  Do you get an error, or is it just not the color you anticipate?  Also, you might want to read [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/104014), which is related.

Comment: Although I'm not sure what you want do about ``for(var i = 2; i <= value; i++){``, in your script, please use ``colors`` as 2 dimensional array. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackgrounds(String)

Comment: @tanaike, I understood when there is a range like the example but not for a undefined range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Value is two-dimensional array, why are you running loop over it ?
2. Colors should be a two-dimensional array. As it'll be setting color in two-dimensional range.

You should try something like this :

```
function new_bg() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var value = range.getValues();
  var colors = [], temp = [];
  for (var i = 2; i <= value.length; i++) {
    temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < value[i-1].length; j++) {
      temp.push("#000000");
    }
    colors.push(temp);
  }
  range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```